# Send an array to a Redux Form to generate options in a select drop down

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

Working on the setting security questions part of the authentication. The server responds with a list of the 20 or so questions in the form of an array. I can get the form and select box to render, but only one option at a time by specifying the index.

If I try to send the entire array I get an `undefined` error. Tried to do a `for loop` in the ` to iterate through each index, which generated an error.

I'm trying to figure out how to pass the entire array so it makes an `option` for each entry in the array.

This is what I have so far:

```
// ./set_security_questions.js

 // This renders errors regarding the form inputs
renderField(field) {
    const { 
        label,
        placeholder,
        type,
        name,
        questions,
        meta: {
            touched, 
            error 
        } 
    } = field;

    return (
        <div className='form-group'>
            <label>{label}</label>
            <select className='form-control' name={name}>
                 <option value={questions}>{questions}
                 </option>}
            </select>
            <input 
                className='form-control' 
                type={type}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                {...field.input} 
            />
            <div className='text-danger'>
                {touched ? error : ""}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}


// The main body to be rendered
render() {
    if (this.props.permitRender) {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>

                <h3>Set Security Questions</h3>
                <p>Please select two security questions that will be easy for you to remember.</p>

                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
                    {this.renderAlert()}

                    <Field
                        questions={this.props.questions.data.security_question}
                        label='Question 1'
                        placeholder='Answer 1'
                        name='a1'
                        type='text'
                        component={this.renderField} 
                    />

                    <Field
                        label='Question 2'
                        placeholder='Answer 2'
                        name='a2'
                        type='text'
                        component={this.renderField} 
                    />
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );            
    } else if (!this.props.permitRender) {
        return ( 
            <div> { this.renderAlert() } </div>
        );
    } 
}
```

In addition, my JSON that comes back from the server looks pretty strange, so I will need to iron that out, but still wondering how to pass an array into the Form. `this.props.questions.data`:

```
 data:
    id: 123
    key: "key_request"
    security_q1: null
    security_q2: null
    security_question: Array(29) 
        0: {security_question: "In what city or town did you meet your spouse / partner?"}
        1: {security_question: "In what city or town did your mother and father meet?"}
        2: {security_question: "In what town or city was your first full time job?"}
        3: {security_question: "What is the first name of your spouse's father?"}
        ......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example I'm currently using to populate a set of checkboxes. There isn't any special logic going on in the checkbox component, I just am using custom html for styling purposes.

Here is my data, a simple array:

```
const env = {
  FONT_FORMATS: ['OTF', 'TTF', 'WOFF', 'WOFF2']
}
```

Here is the code in the render() function for my component. I'm storing each item in the Redux form under the object key -> fileTypes.

```
<ul className='tags'>
    {envConfig.FONT_FORMATS.map((tag: string) => (
      <Field
        key={tag}
        value={tag}
        name={`fileTypes.[${tag}]`}
        id={tag.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '_')}
        type='checkbox'
        component={checkBox}
        label={tag}
      />
    ))}
  </ul>
```

I hope this helps you out!